# Layout MessageBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Como posso customizar o meu MessageBox?
Original..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu gostaria que ficasse (Maior)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria isto que você procura? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201894/A-Customizable-WPF-MessageBox ou https://wpfmessagebox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Eu estava pensando em simplesmente editar o próprio MessageBox do WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível alterar a aparência do Message Box do WPF pois ela não é uma janela criada pelo .Net usando os componentes do WPF, esta janela é basicamente uma chamada a API do Windows, no caso a própria MessageBox do user32.dll

Eu diria que suas melhores alternativas são mesmo criar sua própria janela ou usar algum componente pronto para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Caso não queira utilizar a opção WPF você pode fazer um form mesmo e atribuir os botões e as funcionalidades e criar os DialogResults.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPF toolkit, depois só alterar o layout dele com Style como qualquer outro Control:

https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MessageBox

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?